# pands.read_sql takes a long time to load parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, pandas

I've got a python tuple of about 20,000 user ids that I'd like to pass as a parameter in a query on a MYsql database. The query itself takes a very short time, but it seems to be slowed down by loading the parameter. Is there a way to speed up the parameter load?

I'm using Jupyter Notebook, python 3, pandas, sql_magic, and MySQLdb.

```
import pandas as pd
```

`%load_ext sql_magic`

```
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import MySQLdb
mysql = MySQLdb.connect(host="", user="", passwd="", db = "", port = )
mytuple = ('1111',
 '2222',
 '3333',
 '4444',
 '5555', and a bunch more)
```

.

```
%%read_sql stuff -d
select id
from table
where subscribed_date> '2017-01-01'
    and id in {mytuple}
```

When I copy the query and the 20,000 ids into a sql client the query runs very quickly. Also Jupyter Notebook claims the query took a very short time, but it takes along time until it shows the "Query started at X"

The "and id in {mytuple}" part is the parameter I am referring to.